# How to extract definitions inside aws-cdk typescript stack class constructor function into separate files?

Tags: javascript, aws-cdk

Experimenting with aws-cdk and it's easy to see how the stack/backend construct class files could get quite large. In this cdk Stack class example (copied and pruned from the aws-cdk api-cors-lambda-crud-dynamodb example) is there an idiomatic way to extract the dynamodb, lambda and apigateway constructor definitions out of the stack class constructor function into separate files? They all take `this` as the first argument. I'd like to have a separate file for all the lambda defs, one for the db def, api gateway config, etc that are still referenced inside the main stack class. Is there a way to do this without having to create new classes for each of the definitions?

```
export class ApiLambdaCrudDynamoDBStack extends cdk.Stack {
    constructor(app: cdk.App, id: string) {
        super(app, id);

        const dynamoTable = new dynamodb.Table(this, "items", {
            partitionKey: {
                name: "itemId",
                type: dynamodb.AttributeType.STRING
            },
            tableName: "items"
        });

        const getOneLambda = new lambda.Function(this, "getOneItemFunction", {
            code: new lambda.AssetCode("src"),
            handler: "get-one.handler",
            runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_10_X,
            environment: {
                TABLE_NAME: dynamoTable.tableName,
                PRIMARY_KEY: "itemId"
            }
        });

        const getAllLambda = new lambda.Function(this, "getAllItemsFunction", {
            code: new lambda.AssetCode("src"),
            handler: "get-all.handler",
            runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_10_X,
            environment: {
                TABLE_NAME: dynamoTable.tableName,
                PRIMARY_KEY: "itemId"
            }
        });

        dynamoTable.grantReadWriteData(getAllLambda);
        dynamoTable.grantReadWriteData(getOneLambda);

        const api = new apigateway.RestApi(this, "itemsApi", {
            restApiName: "Items Service"
        });

        const items = api.root.addResource("items");
        const getAllIntegration = new apigateway.LambdaIntegration(getAllLambda);
        items.addMethod("GET", getAllIntegration);

        const singleItem = items.addResource("{id}");
        const getOneIntegration = new apigateway.LambdaIntegration(getOneLambda);
        singleItem.addMethod("GET", getOneIntegration);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah you can separate them into their own stacks. 'LambdaStack', 'DynamoDbStack', etc.

Or you can have just separate 'helper' classes if you don't want it directly in the constructor. Here's a simple C# example:

```
public class ApiLambdaCrudDynamoDbStack : Stack 
{
    internal ApiLambdaCrudDynamoDbStack(Construct scope, string id) : base (scope, id)
    {
        var helper = new MyHelper();
        
        helper.CreateTable(this, "My-Cool-Table"); 
        
    }
}

public class MyHelper
{
    public void CreateTable(Construct scope, string tableName)
    {
        var table = new Table(scope, "My-Table", new TableProps()
        {
             TableName = tableName
        });
    }
}
```